# can we do all model validation false while i insert data from sql file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I m building an app, in which i m populating database using sql dump file (<<*.sql).
I want model validation false while inserting data from Sql File. 
How can it be possible?

Ex..

### User_table

Name | Email

---

user_table << users.sql

user.rb(model)
validate_presence_of :email

want to do all model validation false while i insert data from sql file.

Comment: What's your script to insert data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading data from an SQL file (e.g. using something like `mysql < dump.sql` at the command line) then your validations won't apply.  The validations only apply if you're using ActiveRecord (e.g. using a Ruby script that calls `save` on an instance of the `User` model).

If you find that you can't load your data without using ActiveRecord then the problem is probably your database schema not allowing `NULL` values in certain columns.